# How do I change the local host port when routing with Material-UI in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using a material-ui react button with the `to={''}` property to route to a new page with a different port.

The application runs on localhost:3000 but when I route with this button I want to change to localhost:8080. Right now I am doing it like `to={'${process.env.UAA_HOST}/uaa/create_account'}` which almost works by getting the correct port, but the problem is that it just adds it onto the localhost:3000 such that the route is: http://localhost:3000/http://localhost:8080/uaa/create_account

How do I replace just the port number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React router's `to` method is a router-aware anchor, so it is trying to link within your current page. If you want an external link it is recommended to use a `<a>` tag. You could use this with the material-ui `Button` as follows:

```
const MyLink = () => <a href='${process.env.UAA_HOST}/uaa/create_account'/>

<Button component={MyLink}>
    Link
</Button>
```

See [this](https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/#third-party-routing-library) page of the Material-Ui docs for more details.

An alternative method, is to simply wrap your button in an `<a>` tag or just adding the `href` tag to your button.

ie:

```
<a href='${process.env.UAA_HOST}/uaa/create_account'>  // this
    <Button href='${process.env.UAA_HOST}/uaa/create_account'  // or this>Link here</Button>
</a>
```

Comment: Ah interesting, thanks. The only problem is that I lose the material-ui Button styling. Any idea on how to retain this?

Comment: I am not sure with using the above method, but you could also just wrap your button component in an `<a>` tag. 
ie: `<a href="..."><Button><Button/></a>`

Comment: Ok thanks, I did it another way and that was just simply adding `href='${process.env.UAA_HOST}/uaa/create_account` as a button prop